# Why is Kitaev's toric code a $Z_2$ gauge theory?

Tags: condensed-matter, gauge-theory, topological-field-theory, topological-order, topological-phase

I am reading [Kitaev's 2003 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9707021). In the literature, it is often said that the model proposed in this paper is a $Z_2$ gauge theory. I don't quite see why it is the case. Where is the $Z_2$ gauge symmetry? (I think, of course, there is a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ global gauge symmetry because we can flip all the spins in the Hamiltonian) I would like to know what is the specific $Z_2$ symmetry that people have in mind when talking about the toric code. Would someone please help? Thanks!

---

To add some details to Norbert's answer below. The local $Z_2$ gauge symmetry operator is essentially the plaquette term of the toric code. It is called a $Z_2$ operator because it squares to unity. As to how this toric code gauge theory may be coupled to a matter field [please see this reference](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.3120).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you insist on not breaking one type of terms in the Hamiltonian - say, the plaquette constraints - then the remaining theory is a $Z_2$ gauge theory with the plaquette constraints as the gauge constraints. Thus, within this subspace where the plaquette constraints are not violated, the theory behaves just as a gauge theory.

But this is no longer true when the gauge constraints are broken. However, in that case you can *still* think of it as a gauge theory, but one where you additionally introduce matter - that is, you imagine having additional matter degrees of freedom sitting on the plaquettes, and there is a *joint* gauge constraint for matter and gauge fields.  If the Hamiltonian constraint (=gauge constraint of the pure gauge theory) of a plaquette in the toric code is broken, you can then interpret this as having a matter excitation (=charge) sitting on the plaquette (since then the matter + gauge field gauge constraint is still preserved).

Thus, the Toric Code model can be interpreted as a $Z_2$ gauge theory with matter, where the matter amounts to the violation of the plaquette degrees of freedom.

Comment: Thanks! The answer is very helpful!! If we regard the toric code as a pure gauge theory (whose gauge constraint is energetically imposed), is the $Z_2$ symmetry just the total 'spin-flip' (this total spin-flip operator commutes with the Hamiltonian and has eigenvalues $\pm 1$)? And, we say this symmetry is $Z_2$ because the eigenvalues of this symmetry operator are $\{+ 1, -1\}$?

Comment: @Waterfall Nope, gauge symmetries in a gauge theory are always *local*. In essence, the pure gauge theory is what you get when you set the prefactor in front of the plaquette term to infinity, that is, if you only consider the model on the subspace where each plaquette term is satisfied. Then, the gauge symmetry is flipping all spins around a plaquette in the correct basis (i.e. the action of one plaquette term).

Comment: @ Norbert Schuch, Ah! I see! Thanks!