# Is there a Majorana representation for toric code

Tags: topological-field-theory, topological-insulators, topological-order, topological-phase, lattice-gauge-theory

Kitaev's toric code is known to be the Z2 gauge field theory, which suggests that there might exists a Majorana representation for the toric code, e.g., Majorana + Z2 gauge field. Hence, I wonder if this is true, and what is the concrete Majorana representation.

Comment: May be more appropriate for [Quantum SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @mavzolej Unlikely. Why? Both gauge theories and Majorana fermions belong here.

Comment: Probably not "more appropriate" but maybe worth reposting.

Comment: Some background for the interested reader here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/627100/226902

Answer (score 1):

You can construct Majorana representations of the toric code, but I did not find them particularly insightful. I would be happy if this is not the case, so please let me know if you realize something useful! (maybe something about boundaries?)

Notation $B_p = \prod Z, A_v = \prod X$.

### Approach I

Note that the toric code has a subsystem $Z_2$ symmetry given by $X$ acting on straight horizontal / vertical lines along the dual lattice. This suggests that we can apply a Jordan Wigner transformation along these 1d subsystems, and we will get a consistent local Majorana fermionic description of the toric code by replacing each spin with two Majorana site. In particular, the plaquette terms become 4-Majorana operators (diamond shape) and the vertex terms become 8 Majorana operators (octagon shape). All these operators commute because they have an even number of Majorana sites in common.

### Approach II

The toric code actually has an even larger symmetry group -- a $Z_2$ *one-form* symmetry that is given by applying $X$ on any closed loop on the dual lattice. This motivates a more natural form of "Jordan-Wigner" transformation intrinsic to two dimensions with gauge redundancies. In fact, the Kitaev honeycomb model has a similar one-form symmetry that allows us to get to the exactly solvable Majorana description.

Just like Kitaev did for his honeycomb model, we can replace each spin with 4 Majoranas $\gamma_0,\dots,\gamma_3$ with $\hat\sigma^\mu \equiv i\gamma_0\gamma_\mu$ and the local gauge constraint $\gamma_0\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3 = 1$. Using this language, the toric code becomes a Hamiltonian with two sets of 8-Majorana operators, corresponding to the plaquette and vertex terms respectively. The gauge constraint is a 4 body operator (labelled $G$). Everything is marked in the figure below.

[image: Majorana description of toric code]

Note that, like Kitaev did for the honeycomb model, you can define static, two-Majorana, "link" variables that commute with the Hamiltonian and set them all the be $+1$ for the ground state. This is Majorana system with $Z_2$ gauge fields but without matter fermions.

---

In hindsight, it is obvious why the Majorana description is not so interesting. The toric code is exactly solvable because all the terms commute. This is in contrast to the honeycomb model where there is frustration between the Ising interactions and this manifests as the nontrivial Hamiltonian for the Majorana fermion.